# how to change the values of the object. I am coding on Google Apps Scipts environment

Tags: javascript

let's say the apartment has 4 windows

there is the following array

```
        var windowAction= [
            ["1. open", "1. close"],
            ["2. open", "2. close"],
            ["3. open", "3. close"],  
            ["4. open", "4. close"],
          ];
```

initially, all windows are open.
I wrote this in the form of the following object

```
     var window= {
              "window":[
                [{"action": windowAction[0][0]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[1][0]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[2][0]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[3][0]}]
              ]
            };
```

after closing window number 1, need to change the object to be

```
    var window= {
              "window":[
                [{"action": windowAction[0][1]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[1][0]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[2][0]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[3][0]}]
              ]
            };
```

and if we close the 3rd window, there will be

```
 var window= {
          "window":[
            [{"action": windowAction[0][1]}],
            [{"action": windowAction[1][0]}],
            [{"action": windowAction[2][1]}],
            [{"action": windowAction[3][0]}]
          ]
        };
```

and vice-versa if we open 1st window, it will be

```
     var window= {
              "window":[
                [{"action": windowAction[0][0]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[1][0]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[2][1]}],
                [{"action": windowAction[3][0]}]
              ]
            };
```

please, tell me how to make it changeable  ..

I tried to write with a switch-case, but along the way I realized that it would not work.

I need it exactly in the form of an object

thank you in advance

There is my try:

```
function checker(windowObj, userInput){    
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if (windowAction[i][0] == userInput){
            windowObj[i] = windowAction[i][1];          
        }
        else {
            windowObj[i] = windowAction[i][0];
        }
    }
}

var windowAction = [
    ["1. open", "1. close"],
    ["2. open", "2. close"],
    ["3. open", "3. close"],  
    ["4. open", "4. close"]
];
    
var windowObj = [
    windowAction[0][0],
    windowAction[1][0],
    windowAction[2][0],
    windowAction[3][0]
];



  
var userInput = "1. open";
    
checker(windowObj, userInput);  
print(windowObj);


userInput = "2. open";

checker(windowObj, userInput);  
print(windowObj);


userInput = "1. close";

checker(windowObj, userInput);  
print(windowObj);
```

output should be:

```
1. close,2. open,3. open,4. open
1. close,2. close,3. open,4. open
1. open,2. close,3. open,4. open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't call variables `window`, its JS reserved word among others.

If I understood you correctly, you need a way of changing value of objects specific property?

```
windowobj.window[0][0].action=windowAction[0][1]
```

You can easily target specific ones just follow your indexes.

```js
var windowAction = [
  ["1. open", "1. close"],
  ["2. open", "2. close"],
  ["3. open", "3. close"],
  ["4. open", "4. close"],
];
var windowobj = {
  "window": [
    [{
      "action": windowAction[0][0]
    }],
    [{
      "action": windowAction[1][0]
    }],
    [{
      "action": windowAction[2][0]
    }],
    [{
      "action": windowAction[3][0]
    }]
  ]
};

console.log(windowobj.window[0][0].action)

windowobj.window[0][0].action=windowAction[0][1]

console.log(windowobj.window[0][0].action)
console.log(windowobj.window)
```

EDIT:

If you need automatic changes then you need to structure your arrays/ objects different:

Define your `windowAction` as object not array, where you will have function that returns  open or close status:

```
1:function() { x = ["1. open", "1. close"]; return x[1]},
```

`return` here is what you wont to do with it. `return x[1]` for close, return `x[0]` for open.

Then on `windowobj` object side you invoke that function to get the current value.

```
"action": windowAction[1]()
```

This way you open close then in `windowAction` by changing `0` to `1` and vice-versa and `windowobj` is always updated.

```js
var windowAction = {
  1:function() { x = ["1. open", "1. close"]; return x[1]},
  2:function() { x = ["2. open", "2. close"]; return x[0]},
  3:function() { x = ["3. open", "3. close"]; return x[0]},
  4:function() { x = ["4. open", "4. close"]; return x[0]}
};

console.log(windowAction[1]())



var windowobj = {
  "window": [
    [{
      "action": windowAction[1]()
    }],
    [{
      "action": windowAction[2]()
    }],
    [{
      "action": windowAction[3]()
    }],
    [{
      "action": windowAction[4]()
    }]
  ]
};

console.log(windowobj.window[0])
```

**EDIT2:**

```js
document.querySelector("select").onchange = function (event) {
  let res = event.target.value.split(". ")
  setValue(res[0], res[1])
};

var windowAction
let saveState=[[,],[,],[,],[,]];

function setValue(num, state){

saveState[num-1][0]=num
saveState[num-1][1]=state
//console.log(saveState)

   windowAction = {
    1:function() {if(saveState[0][1] === "close" && saveState[0][0] ==1){x="1. close"}else{x="1. open"}; return x},
    2:function() {if(saveState[1][1] === "close" && saveState[1][0] ==2){x="2. close"}else{x="2. open"}; return x},
    3:function() {if(saveState[2][1] === "close" && saveState[2][0] ==3){x="3. close"}else{x="3. open"}; return x},
    4:function() {if(saveState[3][1] === "close" && saveState[3][0] ==4){x="4. close"}else{x="4. open"}; return x},
  };

//console.log(saveState1)
//windowAction[num](state)



  var windowobj = {
    "window": [
      [{
        "action": windowAction[1]()
      }],
      [{
        "action": windowAction[2]()
      }],
      [{
        "action": windowAction[3]()
      }],
      [{
        "action": windowAction[4]()
      }]
    ]
  };

  console.clear()
  //console.log(windowobj.window[num-1])
  console.log(windowobj.window)

}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
min-height: 70%}
```

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>...</option>

  <option>1. open</option>
  <option>1. close</option>
  <option>2. open</option>
  <option>2. close</option>
  <option>3. open</option>
  <option>3. close</option>
  <option>4. open</option>
  <option>4. close</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yeah, thx for reply. But I need opportunity to change the stored "windowobj" value to the current one, automatically.

Comment: thx! but sir, sorry for asking a such question: how can I use variable(userInput; string type) to update the windowAction? I mean, in my "try"  userInput were compared with windowAction directly.  if it possible, could you please point me to how to interact with '0' and '1' to change windowAction, as a result to update windowObj. Again, Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Salkynbekov I have no idea anymore what you want to achieve.  You talk about that you need objects and then in example you show 2 arrays, not a single object. And your wonted output that you shown has 0 logic and connection with user input. I made one more snippet but I have not time for this anymore, your question and goal is unclear.